# Android call log CursorAdapter shows a few records of each number

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, cursor, adapter

My CursorAdapter shows call log in ListView. I want to show every number just once, but if I did 3 calls to someone this will show the same row 3 times.
I need to show each number one time only.

This is a part of my CursorAdapter:

```
class LogAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        String number = cursor.getString(LogQuery.NUMBER);
        Cursor contactCursor = getContactCursor(number);

        if (contactCursor.getCount() >= 1) {
            String name = contactCursor.getString(ContactsQuery.NAME);
            Uri contactUri = Contacts.getLookupUri(
                    contactCursor.getLong(ContactsQuery.ID),
                    contactCursor.getString(ContactsQuery.LOOKUP_KEY));

            holder.mName.setText(name);
            holder.mNumber.setText(number);
        }
    }

    private Cursor getContactCursor(String number) {
        Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath
                (ContactsQuery.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query
                (contactUri, ContactsQuery.PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor;
    }

}
```